# How to add a bot to Telegram (core app) in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

I can't figure out how to add a bot to the Telegram app that comes with Ubuntu Touch (as of OTA-12) version 2.2.30.0 (Ubuntu Core App Developers).

I already added some contacts (human), but for a bot neither links nor interface actions worked for me.

Is there any way?

If yes, how?

If not, should a bug be reported?

Comment: There are already some reported bugs: http://pad.lv/1569300 & http://pad.lv/1582586. I didn't find any easy way to add bots from the Touch app itself, but I added bots from the desktop client/ Telegram Web, then they showed up in Touch app too.